# Adjusting / place a larger image size imageView Android

Tags: android, imageview

What I want is to open the option to adjust the image by touch inside a hollow (imageview size).

For example, if I add a profile picture, the picture does not come out whole, but through touch I move the image to adjust the settings as you want.

The effect is that after choosing a photo gallery, appears something like this:

[image]

Thanks. Regards.